# What do the different coloured bars on the 1x1 widget in Better Battery Stats app mean?

Tags: battery-life, app-widgets

I understand these are supposed to signify ratios of different phone states but I cannot get my head around which is supposed to be which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about this?

[image]

[Source](https://github.com/asksven/BetterBatteryStats/blob/master/BetterBatteryStats/graphics/Doc_SmallWidget.png).

Comment: Perfect, thank you! My Google skills must be very poor today.... I'll accept shortly after forced delay.